# Omega 4 without Drush

Tags: drush, theming

Hi [still new to Drupal]

Due to certain constraints I can't install drush. Am I able to work on Omega 4 without Drush? The organisation I work for has strict online security and firewall. I have a lot if issues installing drush. So I have decided not to install it and would like ti work on omega 4 without drush.

Does anyone have a good place to start, or can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm look for tutorials, forums anything that can help. This has cost me time and now i need to hit the theme.

Please can you assist?

Comment: I think you need to give it a try and then update your question with a specific problem, as it stands it's unclear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: I suggest looking at the README that comes with Omega4. Drush is recommended but not required, it installs and is useable and sub-themeable as any drupal theme. http://cgit.drupalcode.org/omega/tree/omega/README.md

Comment: Can this question be reopened, I've edited it as you can see I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user Omega without Drush but I do recommend to try to install the Drush. Even if you do not want to use Omega you need to have Drush for serious Drupal projects. It makes your life easy.

Comment: This really helps thanks, where I work i need to explain why I need Drush. Is Drush used as a local tool. I want to allay any security fears IT may have.

Comment: You need to install it on your local system or on your server. Drush can deal only with Drupal so there is no security reason for not using it. Consider it as a script created to let you do the job fast and easy. if you want to install a module just type 'drush en ckeditor -y' and it will download and install ckeditor  module.